# При добавлении модуля в макет ничего не происходит

Tags: php, opencart

Проблема в том, что при добавлении модуля в макет ничего не происходит, хотя на другой странице все работает нормально. Путь прописан корректно, отрисовкой у меня занимается **category_price**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Версия OpenCart'a 2.3

Comment: на странице, куда добавляете, в .tpl файле есть <?php echo $content_top; ?> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это кастомный лейаут, то скорее всего в .tpl этого контроллера забыли добавить контейнер `content_top`

```
<?php echo $content_top; ?>
```